# AWS S3 requests fail with 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch for newly created buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use virtual addressing style to access my items in AWS S3 buckets. For new buckets, I always get status 403:

```xml
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>XXXXXXXXXXX</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>XXXXXXXXXXX</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>XXXXXXXXXXX</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>XXXXXXXXXXX</StringToSignBytes>
<CanonicalRequest>GET /path/tp/image.jpeg X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXXX%2F20230621%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230621T114631Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host host:my-host.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com host UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
<CanonicalRequestBytes>XXXXXXXXXXX</CanonicalRequestBytes>
<RequestId>XXXXXXXXXXX</RequestId>
<HostId>XXXXXXXXXXX</HostId>
</Error>
```

After some hours, this error goes away and everything works fine. I would like to have my buckets work right away. Is there a way to get around this issue?